# How to get rid of a sihr?

Tags: quran, allah, dua, sihr

First of all I apologize for my grammar as english is not my first language and I don’t know what’re the exact words in some sentences. 
So someone did sihr to my best friend and her whole family. Her father already died with that. I don’t really understand these sihr, jinn etc. She said it has been years but they couldn’t figure out how to get rid of it. The person who did sihr to her family is also dead. But they can’t find the sihr( I don’t know what it calls).She has read so many duas and had so many treatments but nothing worked. Now her mother is getting these attacks, like I’ve seen her whole body was shaking and her eyeballs were stuck in the top right corner. 
They tried to get help from the best for sihr bathil & he said that the sihr is hidden in the ocean. The ocean is so huge,It’s almost impossible to find that. Is there anyway they can find it? If so how? 
And is there anyway I can help them? If so, how?

Comment: As far as I know, if the sahr is dead then the sihr should be gone

Comment: Have you consulted a doctor? Could be epilepsy or some other medical condition that causes seizures. The Islamic cure to sihr are the mauwazatain, ayatul Qursi and any verse on sihr. Be wary of any "amils" (witch doctors) as they are usually frauds.

Comment: @Uma yes she did. Few months ego she was bleeding from her nose and mouth & also because having those attacks I’ve mentioned before. Doctors did some tests but nothing showed in the tests. Everything was fine. They couldn’t find the cause of why that’s happening to her. So there’s no other way than to believe it’s because of that sihr.

Comment: @Casanova does that mean someone else who’re still alive also did sihr to her family?

Comment: We need to know exactly what you have done for your ruqyah plan. How does this person know the sihr is In the ocean?